# Determine if PapaParse parsing error is breaking or not

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I'm using PapaParse to handle the CSV parsing for my program. My question is, how can I determine if the errors I receive from the parser are actually breaking?

In the [documentation](http://papaparse.com/docs#errors) it says

> Just because errors are generated does not necessarily mean that
>   parsing failed.

If I have a blocking error (parsing failed), I would like like to redirect the user to an error page, else I would like the program to run normally.

Secondly, does the `complete:` callback run even if parsing failed? Or does it run similarly to a `success:` callback like in Ajax?

Comment: as `complete` is called with `{
 data,
 errors,
 meta
}` it's safe to assume it's always called

Comment: Thanks - That's what I figured. Now I just need to figure out how to determine which errors passed are breaking and which ones are not.

Comment: perhaps check the `aborted`/`truncated` values in the `meta` object? The documentation is a little vague though